# How to remove parentheses and text inside from all rows in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I want to delete parentheses and text inside them from each row. Text inside parentheses varies and "Find and replace" tool cannot be used. What I want to do can be seen from this figure:

[image]

Sometimes in rows parenthesess are absent. What kind of formula I can use so that it removes brackets and text and do not affect rows where no brackets given.

Comment: `=trim(mid(B2,Find(")",B2)+2,999))`

Comment: The `trim` is a nice touch^^

Comment: For those who use silly russian localization of this formula you can use: =СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(B2;НАЙТИ(")";B2)+2;999))

Comment: I think Scott Craner pretty much nailed it. Scott can you add this as an answer so it can show up as closed? The one indication I would give is that if the text position changes in comparison to the text in parenthesis (ie. "A, B, C (No23581)") the formula would need to be changed. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is always the same you can use:

**In English**

=TRIM(MID(B2,FIND(")",B2)+2,999))

**In Russian (For Andrey)**

=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(B2;НАЙТИ(")";B2)+2;999))

To test whether the Cell has a `")"` or not:

```
=IF(NOT( ISERROR(FIND(")",B2))),TRIM(MID(B2,FIND(")",B2)+2,999)),B2)
```

You will need to do the translation.

Edit: The formula above can be written more simply.  I got caught in fixing each problem without realizing there is an easier way.

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(B2,FIND(")",B2)+2,999)),B2)
```

Comment: @AndreyRadik  I added an edit to address if not `")"` is found.

Comment: Unfortunately for rows that do not contain brackets I still receive: “#N/A”. But where brackets presented everything works.

Comment: This worked:) My russian version:  =ЕСЛИ(НЕ( ЕОШИБКА(НАЙТИ(")";B1)));СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(B1;НАЙТИ(")";B1)+2;999));B1)